# AP marca resposta como aceita e diz que não é o que espera

Tags: suporte, comportamento, comunidade, resposta-aceita

Um caso explícito onde o AP marcou uma resposta como aceita e comentou que a resposta não é correta.

Exemplo:

[Pegar parte do conteúdo html armazenado em uma variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114478/pegar-parte-do-conte%C3%BAdo-html-armazenado-em-uma-vari%C3%A1vel)

A questão é, para casos tão explícitos assim não há exceção?

Podemos sinalizar para um moderador?

Salvei screenshot para o caso de haver alterações.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Nada que uma breve orientação nos comentários não resolva. Acredito eu.

Comment: sim, isso é o que normalmente  se aplica, contudo há casos onde o ap ignora ou abandona.

Comment: abandonar não tem o que fazer, se ele abandonou a conta dele, mas se ele abandonou a pergunta, insistir um pouco mais ainda chega na inbox dele, uma hora ele lê. Agora se ele ignora (cara isso é irritante), realmente é complicado, não acho que seja caso de sinalizar, mas ainda sim de dar um puxão de orelha do tipo: *Fulano porque esta me ignorando? Estou tentando lhe orientar e ajudar* então espere responder, o constrangimento é tanto na maioria dos casos que eles respondem (não é um constrangimento ofensivo eu chamo de puxão de orelha).

Comment: Sinalizando no máximo um moderador vai comentar também, acho burocracia. Eu marcaria a pergunta nos favoritos pra me lembrar de voltar lá e dar uma cobrada, se eu voltar ele tiver corrigido então removo dos favoritos. Nesse caso eu acessei a pergunta e parece que ele entendeu, mesmo que ele não tenha dado retorno. Nem todos usuários entendem que as vezes um "foi mal, entendi agora" é importante pra termos certeza.

Comment: esse é o ponto.  E discordo disso de termos que agir como babás..  concordo apenas com um unico e simples aviso, mas aí chegar ao ponto de ficar atrás do sujeito pedindo para arrumar, acho exagero.  O ponto é, nesses casos onde fica assim com a resposta marcada errada, não há exceção para, por exemplo, um moderador modificar removendo a aceitação da reposta marcada erroneamente?  Não seria muito mais simples e prático, para casos explícitos como esse, um moderador ter opção de modificar? Seria muito menos burocrático e simples, aliás eficiente.

Comment: Concordo plenamente, seria interessante ter essa ferramente pros moderadores (devem ter), mas pode ser chato pra ti e já tem pessoas que costumam orientar não, na verdade se mais pessoas fizessem isso não nos sentiríamos tanto babás. Na verdade se as pessoas fizessem o tour com atenção isso seria raro. São *n* situações. Todavia talvez seja melhor um mod responder se pode sinalizar, é que vejo tantos comentários de *fulano faça isso*, *não faça aquilo*, que acho que é normal até o cara aprender. Vou admitir não tenho paciência também, mas vai de cada um né?

Comment: É isso que acho redundante aqui no SO-pt, pois alguns acabam agindo como babás. Como se aqui fosse um centro de suporte técnico atendendo clientes.

Comment: Eu sei, eu sei... A questão que tem quem se incomode e tem quem não, somos uma comunidade, somos pessoas diferentes, tem quem é acostumado e aplicado a aprender como funciona, tem quem ache que isso é um fórum, tem maneiras de ensinar orientando e tem outras que a ferramenta proporciona. É só isso que quero dizer, como eu disse talvez possa sinalizar, eu só dei uma sugestão do que muitos usuários costumam fazer, não sei se é o melhor caminho, apenas faz parte da cultura orientar, quem sabe no futuro quem você orientou venha a fazer o mesmo por outro novo usuário? Entende?

Answer (score 4):

Esquece o AP...

Creio que o mais importante é fazer sua resposta o melhor que puder pro que foi perguntado. Chega um momento que melhor do que a "aceitação" ou "correção" do AP, são as *views* que aquela pergunta alcançou, quantas pessoas ajudou.

Depois de se preocupar em responder, ficam as alternativas:

1. Editar a pergunta -sem alterar a idéia original- para fazer o título se destacar no SEO e o texto/formatação ficarem o mais claro possíveis para os futuros visitantes.
2. Mesmo não tendo caprichado na resposta nem feito um upgrade na pergunta, muito sinceramente, acho que é bobagem ficar se preocupando por um AP que não está nem aí pro seu empenho em ajudar. No fundo, a pessoa só quer um trecho de código pra fazer copy/paste e tocar a vida pra frente; que se dane o "obrigado".
   *Ah, o AP não tem nem idéia do que está fazendo?* Whooops... :D

> A questão é, para casos tão explícitos assim não há exceção?

Não, não há exceção. O trabalho dos moderadores não é conferir se uma pergunta/resposta estão corretas tecnicamente. Nem a gente pode colocar o AP num canto e arrancar um comportamento "correto". Esse trabalho de editar, comentar, votar e melhorar o conteúdo fica pra comunidade; se der certo, ótimo, se não, *próxima pergunta*.

Comment: Exatamente. Além disso, não há nada que moderadores (ou a equipe do SO) possa fazer sobre aceitações indevidas...